# Maya UI - A master in every Tab

Tags: python, user-interface, maya

I have created a UI in python for Maya, and I'm using **`tabLayout`** to have many **`rowColumnLayout`** (Tabs) in my user interface. In each Tab I want the top part to have a `Master` that will be the same for every Tab, but without having duplicate instances for each tab because it won't update properly. By that I mean that when I change something in one Tab it won't update in the other tabs.

Here is a simplified example of my problem, I'm using a function `MasterTab` in each Tab :

```
import maya.cmds as cmds

def ChangeText(*arg) : cmds.text('thatText', edit=True, label='Bye')
def MasterTab(*arg) : 
    cmds.button(label='Press Me', command = ChangeText)
    cmds.text('thatText', label='Hello')

cmds.window( widthHeight=(200, 150) )
form = cmds.formLayout()
tabs = cmds.tabLayout(innerMarginWidth=5, innerMarginHeight=5)
cmds.formLayout( form, edit=True, attachForm=((tabs, 'top', 0), (tabs, 'left', 0), (tabs, 'bottom', 0), (tabs, 'right', 0)) )

child1 = cmds.rowColumnLayout(numberOfColumns=2)
# Part I want in every tab
MasterTab()
# Tab One
cmds.text(label='text of tab One', h=50, align='left')
cmds.setParent( '..' )

child2 = cmds.rowColumnLayout(numberOfColumns=2)
# Part I want in every tab
MasterTab()
# Tab Two
cmds.text(label='text of tab Two', h=50, align='left')
cmds.setParent( '..' )

cmds.tabLayout( tabs, edit=True, tabLabel=((child1, 'One'), (child2, 'Two')) )

cmds.showWindow()
```

When I press the button the text showing 'Hello' will only change to 'Bye' in the second Tab for some reason. So if I can't just call my `MasterTab` function in every Tab, would there be a way to call it only once and it would attach in every tab ? Or if there is another way I'm open to suggestions.

Thank you for your help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're hard-coding the name of the text object you want to change as `thatText`.  However the second time you call `MasterTab()` you will define a new text (probably `thatText1`) which Maya will rename so it has a unique ID -- meaning `ChangeText()` will never get to it.

You should probably capture the name of your the text object created in `MasterTab()` and use it there:

```
def MasterTab():
    btn = cmds.button(label='Press Me')
    # use a '#' in the name to get a unique number suffix....
    edit_me = cmds.text('edit_me#', label='Hello')

    # define the handler here, when you know what 'edit_me' is...        
    def change_text(_):
        cmds.text(edit_me, e=True, label = 'bye')

    # now attach the command...
    cmds.button(btn, e=True, c=change_text)
```

More detail on the nuances of scoping these commands [here](http://theodox.github.io/2014/maya_callbacks_cheat_sheet)

Comment: Thank you for your answer ! I thought it might be a renaming problem.. But with this code the button only changes the text for the same tab and not every tab like I would need. If I can't find a simple way of instancing the fields I guess I will have to do a work-around to apply the changes for every field in every tab.

Comment: There's really no analogy in Maya for the idea of a global value like that. Your best bet is to store all of the state in a shared variable and then use the variable to update your UI in a `preSelectCommand` hook in the tabLayout